# Countdown Timers Slowing Down Page: How to create multiple running countdown timers for a single page?

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to create a website that has multiple countdown timers running on the page simultaneously, including possibly showing the milliseconds.

So far I've been using *setInterval()* functions, but after having just a few *setIntervals()* running, the page begins slowing down, the seconds start slowing down and lagging, etc. and it doesn't work.

How do professional sites like [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com), Toggl, or Harvest, allow you to use multiple countdown timers all at the same time, without slowing the page down, that are always perfectly in-sync with the current time? With no lag or problems?

I want to have maybe 25 countdown timers all running on the page at once, without slowing down the page, or having to send hundreds of requests per-second to the server?

I'm trying to create a personal To Do app that sets timers for each task, and I want to see the timers running for all tasks for the entire day.

Comment: Why do you need 25 timers? Can't you just have one setInterval, and modify 25 different variables?

Comment: *"...hundreds of requests per-second to the server"*: how did a server end up in this story?

Answer (score 0):

I would first start using moment.js, as it makes your time with javascript super fast.

Now, when you create a task, you store the timestamp of when it should expire using moment.js.

Then you have a global timer that gets the time every second.

Going in milliseconds is a bad idea because the event loop will slow down time itself in your application.  (Every second wont be 100% accurate, but it will get the correct time, every browser-second).

This global timer will fire functions that update each task timer, comparing the current time with the task expiry time.

No need for 25 timers! Just one timer that handles a function to calculate the difference of two times!